# conditional probability results in value greater than 1

Tags: conditional-probability, natural-language

I am not an expert in probability theory so please bare with me. Suppose I have a one sentence corpus as follows:
**How to go about it**
It's quite obvious to see that the corpus has 5 words. Here is how I am calculating the conditional probability

$P(w_{i} | w_{i-1}) = P(w_{i-1} w_{i}) / P(w_{i-1})$
let $w_{i} = about$, and $w_{i-1} = go$, then
$P(about | go) = (1/4) / (1/5)$
$P(about | go) = 0.25 / 0.20$ which results in **1.25**

Here is how i have picked the numbers to plug into the formula
**Numerator 1 / 4:** 'go about' occurs once(1) / total number of pairs in the corpus are 4 i.e. (how to, to go, go about, and about it)
**Denominator 1 / 5:** go occurs once (1) / total words in corpus are 5

I have read that probability estimates are between 0 and 1 whereas the result I have obtained is greater than 1. **Could anyone please guide me where i am going wrong in my calculations?**

Comment: The first equation is incorrect. Haven't checked anything else though

Comment: @Taylor, can you please specify what is incorrect in first equation, and what is the correct version

Comment: You're supposed to divide by the marginal of the rv you're conditioning on

Comment: receiving feedback from Taylor and Kostia I am editing the question to correct the formula, so that the quotient contains $P(w_{i-1})$ instead of $P(w_{i})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, the interpretation you give to $\mathbf P(w_i|w_{i-1})$ is:

$$\text{what is the probability of having word}\,w_i\text{ next to the word }w_{i-1}$$

In this case the probability can be found by computing the total number of times the sequence $w_{i-1}\,w_i$ appears in the corpus divided by the number of times that the word $w_{i-1}$ appear in the corpus.

Comment: Yes your understanding coincides with what i am trying to compute.

Comment: In the example you gave the probability you want is 1. In a larger corpus, for example: "Although the story covers only a few weeks in the final year of the war" you will find P(story|the) = 1/3 since there are three "the" in the corpus but only one of them is followed by a "story".

Comment: I am still thing about the two approaches the one you mentioned and the one posted by Kostia below, which measure should i take? do these two different ways and values means and represent the same thing?

Comment: The different approaches result from different interpretations of your question and they do not mean the same thing. I believe that you misused the concept of conditional probability in your question. That is why I started my answer by asking if I got your question right. I believe that the probability you want to compute is $P(w_{i-1}w_i\,|\,w_{i-1}(*))$ where $(*)$ means "any word".

Answer (score 4):

To start with, the definition of conditional probability is $\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\mathbb{P}(A,B)/\mathbb{P}(B)$. So, in your first equation, you should have $\mathbb{P}(w_{i-1})$ in the denominator.

Assuming that 5 words ("How", ...) take their positions in a sentence at random, the total number of ordered pairs is 20. This will result into conditional probability (1/20)/(1/5)=1/4, which makes perfect sense: given that $w_{i-1}=go$, $w_i$ can be any of the remaining 4 words.